# French-style quotes look ugly

Tags: punctuation

I want to use French-style quotes like so: «Quote»

So i replaced the quotes with `\flqq{}` and `\frqq{}` but unfortunately it looks very ugly (see example) is there a way to have the french quotes looking good ? (like in this text)

[image: frenchquotes]

edit: I need to use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` to use e.g. Umlauts (ä,ö,ü)

Comment: are you writing in German? (You don't need babel to use  ä,ö,ü )

Comment: The style of quote is just the style of a character in the font, so it depends entirely on what fonts (and font encoding) you are using, but you have not given any clues.

Comment: package `csquotes` handles this stuff quite good. T1 encodng and maybe `lmodern` might be a good idea as well.

Comment: The appearance of the quotes is determined by the font. But for me the symbol in your screenshot looks like the math operator `\gg`… hmm

Comment: French quotes that look like the maths operators `\ll` `\gg` is a symptom of not using T1 encoding. Do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Answer (score 6):

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} results in correct «French Quotes»

Comment: If you write in French, don't forget to load `babel` with option `french` in order to insert non-breaking spaces of proper length between quotes and word (the quotes are then given by the commands `\og` and `\fg`).

Comment: In `utf8` or `latin1` input encoding, you can enter directly french quotes if you have them on your keyboard (some extended keyboard drivers give access to them).

Answer (score 6):

I write in german and use french quotation marks too. I like the package `csquotes`, because it also manages nested quotes. Here is a mwe for french quotation marks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
Thomas fragte: \enquote{Hä? hat Sabine wirklich \enquote{Ich hasse Dich.} gesagt?}
\end{document}
```

This way also has the advantage that when necessary you are able to change the appearance of the quotation marks easily by changing the option of the csquotes-package...